# SSRS report not showing in full page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am  creating report to SSRS 2008 , when i deploy to server the report is just not showing properly, anyone can help?
sorry for my bad English. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ts3N.png)

Comment: What happens if you open the report in internet explorer?

Comment: I tested it work fine in IE but fail in firefox and chrome

Comment: SSRS 2008 doesn't work correctly in browsers other than IE. Even in later version of IE you might need set compatibility mode.